# Drawing curves with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, technical-drawing, draw

Using LaTeX how can I draw a generic smooth closed curve (in 2D) and one other generic smooth curve joining two points on the first curve? I also need to write labels for the curves and each of the domains in which they divide the space.

---

The most I can do with LaTeX (with respect to drawings) is plotting cirlces, ellipses and circle arcs as follows

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\draw (2,2) circle (3cm);
\draw (2,2) ellipse (3cm and 1cm);
\draw (3,0) arc (0:75:3cm);
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Example of closed curve:
[image]

Example of Jordan curve (closed) - from Mathworld:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems a bit too generic. Can you improve your question?

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment. What do you have in mind? For example, I've added a picture of closed curve that I'd like to draw.

Comment: Ti*k*Z has the option `\draw polt[smooth cycle] coordinates {....};` and the `hobby` library adds many more such options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a dedicated library for that, `hobby`. However, something similar to your curves can be drawn with plain Ti*k*Z. Note that I didn't attempt to reproduce them very precisely since you seem to want generic curves.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[set mark/.style args={#1 at #2}{postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #2 with #1}}}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=Jordan]
  \draw plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2.5,0.5) (-1.5,0.5) (-1.5,-0.5)
  (-2,-0.5) (-2,0)};
  \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=1.1] coordinates {(60:1) (-70:1) (-120:1) (110:1)};
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north] at (Jordan.south) {Jordan curves};
 %
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=nonJordan,xshift=5cm]
  \draw (-1.5,1) to[out=-110,in=180] (-1.2,-1) to[out=0,in=-70] (-0.9,1);
  \draw (-0.3,1) to[out=-110,in=0] (0,-1) to[out=180,in=-70] (0.3,1);
  \draw (1.3,-1) to[out=90,in=-90] (2.1,1) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.5] (1.5,1)
  to[out=-90,in=90] (1.9,-1) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1.5] cycle;
 \end{scope}
 \node[anchor=north] at (nonJordan.south) {Non--Jordan curves};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
   \draw[set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {1};}} at 0,set mark={\coordinate (1);} at 0.25,
  set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {2};}} at 0.5,set mark={\coordinate (2);} at 0.75] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1.1] coordinates {(60:1) (-70:1) (-120:1) (110:1)};
  \draw (1) to[out=30,in=150] node[midway,below right] {3} (2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the very right you see how one may connect two points on the curve by another curve, and how they can be labeled.

Comment: That's great. How do I add another smooth curve joining two points on the first one and labels in all the parts in which they divide the space?

Comment: @Zyl I added an example how one could do that (hoping I interpreted it correctly).

Comment: That's great. One other thing: how can we make the picture slightly bigger? And what parameters should I change to modify the shape of that last curve a bit? For example, make it more irregular or change its shape (into something similar to the first curve)?

Comment: @Zyl You can make it bigger by either choosing different coordinates or saying e.g.  `\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Jordan,scale=1.5]`, i.e. add `scale=....` where ... is larger than 1. So try e.g. `\begin{scope}[xshift=14cm,scale=2]
   \draw[set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {1};}} at 0,set mark={\coordinate (1);} at 0.25,
  set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {2};}} at 0.5,set mark={\coordinate (2);} at 0.75]
  plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2.5,0.5) (-1.5,0.5) (-1.5,-0.5)
  (-2,-0.5) (-2,0)};
  \draw (1) to[out=150,in=-30] node[midway,above] {3} (2);
 \end{scope}`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Can we also put a color in the various regions of the space divided by the curve?

Comment: @Zyl Yes, but this deserves a new question IMHO. It is slightly more involved, but can be done with the pgfplots (!) library fillbetween. Putting the curves in a bigger box is comparatively easy: you already have the local bounding boxes, so if you add `\draw (Jordan.south west) rectangle (Jordan.north east);`, you'll get your box.

Comment: Done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471883/plot-curves-and-color-space-regions-in-latex

Comment: Oh, I see. Yup, the box works perfectly. I assume that in the same way I could add a left/right pointing arrow at the boundary (or at the crossing line (3)). How can I add them?

Comment: @Zyl I added some arrows [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471884/121799).