# Plot curves and color space regions in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

In an answer to a previous question ([Drawing curves with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471847/drawing-curves-with-latex/471851?noredirect=1#comment1189327_471851)), this curve was drawn

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[set mark/.style args={#1 at #2}{postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #2 with #1}}}]
 \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
   \draw[set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {1};}} at 0,set mark={\coordinate (1);} at 0.25,
  set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {2};}} at 0.5,set mark={\coordinate (2);} at 0.75] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1.1] coordinates {(60:1) (-70:1) (-120:1) (110:1)};
  \draw (1) to[out=30,in=150] node[midway,below right] {3} (2);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to rewrite the code above in order to put colors in the regions of the space divided by the curve?

Comment: yes, it is possible. in general with option `fill=<color> in your `\draw` command.

Comment: @marmot, i agere your statements in answer, that question should be well defined. according to your opinion, i misunderstood this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `fillbetween`. In this case you could also work with clip, but in general this won't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[set mark/.style args={#1 at #2}{postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #2 with #1}}}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=graph]
   \draw[set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {1};}} at 0,set mark={\coordinate (1);} at 0.25,
  set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {2};}} at 0.5,set mark={\coordinate (2);} at 0.75,
  name path global=contour]
   plot[smooth cycle,tension=1.1] coordinates {(60:1) (-70:1) (-120:1) (110:1)};
  \draw[name path global=divide] (1) to[out=30,in=150] node[midway,below right] {3} (2);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[blue,intersection segments={of=contour and divide,
 sequence={L*}}];
  \fill[red,intersection segments={of=contour and divide,
 sequence={R2--L2[reverse]}}];
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And as for your comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471847/drawing-curves-with-latex/471851?noredirect=1#comment1189343_471851), this is a way to attach arrows to the divide line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,backgrounds}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[set mark/.style args={#1 at #2}{postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,mark=at position #2 with #1}}},
attach arrow/.style={set mark={{\draw[-latex] (0,0.3) -- (0,0);}} at #1}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=graph]
   \draw[set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {1};}} at 0,set mark={\coordinate (1);} at 0.25,
  set mark={{\node at (0,0.3) {2};}} at 0.5,set mark={\coordinate (2);} at 0.75,
  name path global=contour]
   plot[smooth cycle,tension=1.1] coordinates {(60:1) (-70:1) (-120:1) (110:1)};
  \draw[name path global=divide,attach arrow/.list={0.1,0.2,...,0.9}] (1) to[out=30,in=150] node[midway,below right] {3} (2);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[blue,intersection segments={of=contour and divide,
 sequence={L*}}];
  \fill[red,intersection segments={of=contour and divide,
 sequence={R2--L2[reverse]}}];
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note also that this is a public Q & A site. It lives from well-defined questions getting well-defined answers. If a question gets "blurred" by many additional requests, the answer won't be very useful for anyone but the one asking the question. On the other hand, if you ask a new well-defined question, then others may benefit. Askinq questions is free of charge.

Comment: That works very well, thanks. Is it possible to move the arrow so that the "base" is on the line (instead of the "tip") and to adjust the arrow's length?

Comment: @Zyl Yes, of course. The arrow parameters are determined by the `attach arrow` style. If you use e.g. `attach arrow/.style={set mark={{\draw[latex-] (0,0.2) -- (0,0);}} at #1}`, the arrow will be shorter (since `0.3` has been replaced by `0.2`) and the head will point away from the line (since `latex-` has been replaced by `-latex`).