# Shading region of circle with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to shade in the area of a circle that is cut into three pieces. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,positioning, calc, decorations.markings, 
hobby, quotes,angles,decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= white,
xmin=-15, 
xmax=15, 
ymin=-15, 
ymax=15, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
ticks=none,
xlabel = {},
ylabel = {},
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
]

\draw[black, thick, name path=1] (0,0) circle [radius=12];

\addplot[black, domain=-12:12, samples=300, name path = 1] {sqrt(144-x^2)};

\addplot[black, domain=-12:12, samples=300, name path = 2] {-sqrt(144-x^2)};

\draw[white, name path=3] (-12,0) -- (12,0);

\draw[black, dashed] (-3.179,-11.5713) -- (-3.179,11.5713);

\draw[black, dashed] (3.179,-11.5713) -- (3.179,11.5713);

%\addplot[red, fill opacity=0.20] fill between [of=1 and 2,soft clip= 
{domain=-12:-3.179}];


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Slicing the pie into three pieces of equal area.}

\label{pie}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the image produced when I leave the last part commented out:

[image]

Now, when I uncomment out the last line, this is the result.

[image]

While I have the desired shading, the image is now slightly off-center and the axis lines have been drawn, even though I do not want them to. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: You are missing `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` and `\end{document}`, and when I add these I cannot reproduce the issue you are reporting.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added all of the tikz libraries I had in this, so maybe it could be one of those. I have just been adding them as a learn how to draw more with tikz, so maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Using `fillbetween` does more than one may expect. It also sets layers (because the fills are made behind the plots) . With `hide axis` you can solve it, though.

Answer (score 3):

As for the original question: `fillbetween` is less "innocent" than one may think, it also sets layers in such a way that the fills are behind the plots. (This is something that I learned from a comment by Stefan Pinnow.) However, the simplest way to get rid of the axes is to say `hide axis`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[hide axis,
xmin=-15, 
xmax=15, 
ymin=-15, 
ymax=15, 
axis equal image, 
font=\scriptsize,
]

\draw[black, thick, name path=1] (0,0) circle [radius=12];

\addplot[black, domain=-12:12, samples=300, name path = 1] {sqrt(144-x^2)};

\addplot[black, domain=-12:12, samples=300, name path = 2] {-sqrt(144-x^2)};


\draw[black, dashed] (-3.179,-11.5713) -- (-3.179,11.5713);

\draw[black, dashed] (3.179,-11.5713) -- (3.179,11.5713);

\addplot[red, fill opacity=0.20] fill between [of=1 and 2,soft clip= 
{domain=-12:-3.179}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Slicing the pie into three pieces of equal area.}
\label{pie}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet, if you do not want the axes, why don't you just draw the thing with `tikz`? (In any case, I'd recommend using polar coordinates for that.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (6);
\fill[red, fill opacity=0.20] (105:6) rectangle (-6,-6);
\draw[dashed] (105:6) -- (-105:6) (75:6) -- (-75:6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note also that one *can* use the pgfplots library `fillbetween`, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471884/121799). (I'm not claiming that this answer is particularly original, it is just an example that I had at hand.)

As for your last comment: this is what I suggested

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{4}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (\radius);
\fill[red, fill opacity=0.20] (105:\radius) rectangle (-\radius,-\radius);
\fill[blue, fill opacity=0.20] ({-\radius*sin(15)},\radius) rectangle ({\radius*sin(15)},-\radius);
\fill[green, fill opacity=0.20] (75:\radius) rectangle (\radius,-\radius);
\draw[dashed] (105:\radius) -- (-105:\radius) (75:\radius) -- (-75:\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the coordinates used when shaping the red? I am also trying to shade in all three areas using different colors, so I would like to know!

Comment: Also for me, when I use ```hide axis```, the image is still off center and there is a blank white line across the red shaded region.

Comment: @AidenKenny Your coordinate `(-3.179,11.5713)` looks *very* much like `(-12*sin(15),12*cos(15))`, which is `(95:12)` in polar coordinates. The `clip` option makes sure that only the region in the circle gets shaded. So I shade a rectangle with upper right corner `(95:6)` (because I reduced the radius) and a lower left corner that is far away enough. As for your pgfplots comment: I removed the white line from my code, did you compile the code from my answer?

Comment: @AidenKenny To color all regions, try e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{4}
\draw[clip] (0,0) circle (\radius);
\fill[red, fill opacity=0.20] (105:\radius) rectangle (-\radius,-\radius);
\fill[blue, fill opacity=0.20] ({-\radius*sin(15)},\radius) rectangle ({\radius*sin(15)},-\radius);
\fill[green, fill opacity=0.20] (75:\radius) rectangle (\radius,-\radius);
\draw[dashed] (105:\radius) -- (-105:\radius) (75:\radius) -- (-75:\radius);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: The code for filling in all of the regions does not work completely. There are two colored rectangles but they do not fill in the entire circle.

Comment: @AidenKenny I cannot reproduce your statement. I added the code and the output to my answer. If you get something different, then it would be useful to know what compiler you are using and which TeX installation you have.